# Goodness of fit for logistic regression in r

Tags: r, regression, logistic, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I am running a logistic regression model in r programming and wanted to know the goodness of fit of it since the command does not give out the f-test value as in the linear regression models.

So I used the following command:

```
summary( glm( vomiting ~ age, family = binomial(link = logit) ) )

# Call:
# glm(formula = vomiting ~ age, family = binomial(link = logit))

# Deviance Residuals:
#    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -1.0671  -1.0174  -0.9365   1.3395   1.9196 

#  Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
#  (Intercept) -0.141729   0.106206  -1.334    0.182   
#  age         -0.015437   0.003965  -3.893 9.89e-05 ***
#  ---
#  Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' '

#  (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1
#  Null deviance: 1452.3  on 1093  degrees of freedom
#  Residual deviance: 1433.9 on 1092  degrees of freedom

#  AIC: 1437.9
#  Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Then I run  the following which I got some idea from someone else and get:

```
 1-pchisq(1452.3-1433.9, 1093-1092)
 # [1] 1.79058e-05
```

May I know in detail what the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis are
and what this 1.79058e-05 value means in this case?

Comment: I suggest to use the Hosmer-Lemeshow goodness of fit test for logistic regression which is implemented in the `ResourceSelection` library with the `hoslem.test` function. See: http://thestatsgeek.com/2014/02/16/the-hosmer-lemeshow-goodness-of-fit-test-for-logistic-regression/

Comment: Thank you but I am a bit confused. So from the above example if my final 1-pchisq(1452.3-1433.9, 1093-1092) is 1.79058e-05, does this mean my logistic regression model is a good fit or not..?

Comment: I agree with @RuiBarradas. The test that you are using is not a goodness-of-fit test but a likelihood ratio test for the comparison of the proposed model with the null model. P=1.79058e-05 means that the fit of your model is significantly better than the fit of the null model

Comment: Like @MarcoSandri says, your model is significantly better than the model `vomiting ~ 1`, which is basically a computation of the means. Read the link I've provided you with.

Comment: @Rui Barradas: Thank you but it seems like your provided link is gone now..

Comment: @Marco Sandri: Thank you. So when I officially report this result, if I want to call it some sort of 'chi-square test' result, shall I simply put out the pchisq(1452.3-1433.9, 1093-1092) without subtracting it from 1 and report this as an evidence for a type of goodness-of-fit? The Wikipedia says "a likelihood ratio test is a statistical test used for comparing the goodness of fit of two statistical models".

Comment: @Eric No. If you want to make a goodness-of-fit test on your logistic regression model, use the Hosmer-Lemeshow test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosmer%E2%80%93Lemeshow_test The test statistic asymptotically follows a chi-square distribution.

Comment: @Marco Sandri: Thank you again. I tried running the test using hoslem.test() function in r. If the p-value is greater than 0.05, does this mean my model is in good fit?

Comment: @Eric The Hosmer–Lemeshow test determine if the differences between observed and expected proportions are significant. If your p is greater than 0.05, than you can say that you have a good fit.

Comment: @Marco Sandri: However, there is a post that uses my method https://www.r-bloggers.com/veterinary-epidemiologic-research-glm-evaluating-logistic-regression-models-part-3/

Comment: @Marco Sandri: But the strange thing is that using your method and my method sometimes give different conclusions.

Comment: @Marco Sandri: For instance, if I call my logistic regression as "test", then I run "hoslem.test(test$y, fitted(test))" but the conclusion for some cases are not a good fit while 1-pchisq(1452.3-1433.9, 1093-1092) gives good fit. Should I ignore my method and follow yours?

Comment: @Marco Sandri: Oh sorry my mistake..both give the same conclusion. I was confused with the value of "1" from my method as good fit..Thank you so much anyways!

Comment: @Marco Sandri: Yes but no worries it was my misunderstanding. Both gives same conclusions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67473/discussion-between-marco-sandri-and-eric).

Comment: @Eric Link: [Likelihood ratio test in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6505/likelihood-ratio-test-in-r).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use the Hosmer-Lemeshow goodness of fit test for logistic regression which is implemented in the `ResourceSelection` library with the `hoslem.test` function. See: thestatsgeek.com/2014/02/16/ - Marco Sandri

But as @kjetilbhalvorsen points out below, Frank Harrell [disagrees](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18772/121522):

> The Hosmer-Lemeshow test is to some extent obsolete because it
>   requires arbitrary binning of predicted probabilities and does not
>   possess excellent power to detect lack of calibration. It also does
>   not fully penalize for extreme overfitting of the model. Better
>   methods are available such as
>
> Hosmer, D. W.; Hosmer, T.; le Cessie, S.
>   & Lemeshow, S. A comparison of goodness-of-fit tests for the logistic
>   regression model. *Statistics in Medicine*, 1997, **16**, 965-980
>
> Their new measure is implemented in the R `rms` package.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @MarcoSandri as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

Comment: Please see this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18750/hosmer-lemeshow-vs-aic-for-logistic-regression  by Frank Harrell for diverging opinion! He seems to think Hosmer-Lemeshow is obsolete

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks, edited to include that disagreement.